# Prevent the script from loading unless the user triggers a specific function

Tags: javascript, html

I want to prevent the Script from loading unless the function `window.onclick()` is not triggered.

So that the steps should be like:

`1. Page loads`

`2. A dialog box appears as a div tag`

`3. User clicks on the screen`

`4. The box closes`

`5. The script starts working`

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Loading script dynamically. Keep in mind some time we will have libs that are dependent on some other library.
By default browser loads them synchronously. To do the same thing
Follow logic will help you.

```
const loadScript = (document, script) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.onload = resolve;
    newScript.onerror = reject;
    newScript.async = true;
    newScript.appendChild(document.createTextNode(script.innerHTML));
    Array.from(script.attributes).forEach(attr => newScript.setAttribute(attr.name, attr.value));
    script.parentNode.appendChild(newScript);
  })
}

  for (let index = 0; index < scripts.length; index++) {
    try {
      const script = scripts[index];
      // Loading the scripts synchronously to resolve the prior dependencies
      await loadScript(doc, script);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Failed at loading scripts: ', error)
    }
  }
```